# PHP Date Format returning incorrect suffix ('S')

Tags: php, date, time

I have a Unix Timestamps such as `1423389830` and `1511367992`. I'm using a simple [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function: `date( 'M nS, Y', $timestamp );` and it seems like it's returning the wrong date, with the appropriate suffix - which output some rather silly results.

Using the following sample code:

```
printf( '[%s] [%s]', date( 'M nS, Y', 1423389830 ), date( 'M nS, Y', 1511367992 ) );
```

On 3 servers: Mine, [PHPTester.net](http://phptester.net/), and [OnlinePHPFucntions.com](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/), the result is

```
[Feb 2th, 2015] [Nov 11nd, 2017]
```

Dropping those timestamps into [EpochConverter.com](https://www.epochconverter.com/) I get and `Sunday, February 8, 2015 2:03:50 AM GMT-08:00` and `Wednesday, November 22, 2017 8:26:32 AM GMT-08:00`, respectively. February's date is 6 days early - and November's is 11 days early.

You can see an example here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/605415e0490af3e8e1dc3cf12ce9e1ec9ea2b3b6

Answer (score 0):

So, as I wrote out this question, I realized that the day that was output was the same number as the month's number (Feb = 2nd month, November is the 11th month).

This lead me to look back at my date format and I realized I used the wrong format... the `n` should be a `d` or `j`: `date( 'M jS, Y', $timestamp );`.

I figured I'll leave this for (rather embarrassing) posterity - and hopefully to help anyone who sees their PHP Date Suffix returning humorously incorrect to **check their Date Format String** and make sure you're actually using the appropriate/desired format